# How to Open a page, then call a function in Master Page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Below is my code, I'm a beginner. But I hope I can explain my problem well, thanks in advance.

**Page 2**

```
<asp:linkButton ID="LinkData" runat="server" > Data </asp:LinkButton>  // START HERE

Code Behind

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
LinkData.Attributes.Add('onClick', 'javascript:ClickData();return false;');
}
```

**Master Page**

```
<script>
       function ClickData() {
           window.location.href=('Page1.aspx');
          ShowData2();   // ???????????
       }
</script>


<script>

function ShowData2() {           
var Panel = document.getElementById("divData1")
if (Panel.style.display == "none" || Panel.style.display == "") {
Panel.style.display = "block";          
                document.getElementById("DataGraph").style.display = "none";
 }
 else {
 Panel.style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("DataGraph").style.display = "block";
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: `window.location.href=('Page1.aspx')` is invalid code, should be `window.location.href= 'Page1.aspx'`, also you can just do `window.location =..` as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href=('Page1.aspx')` is invalid code, should be `window.location.href= 'Page1.aspx'`, also you can just do `window.location =..` as a shortcut.

Your function `ShowData2` won't get called because you're changing the url before the function can be called.

Comment: Sweet thanks for reply...  Yes I can link and open Page1, but I can't run or call ShowData2 inside Page 1.

Comment: Opps sorry I mis read your reply, How can I do that? calling the function then changing the url? Sorry...